# What is the best way for approaching dynamic Auth Guards?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to package my own AuthGuard for use in other projects and need to pass it a string before use.

Because I saw the `Passport` auth guard use a function that wrapped around a new class I've done the same...

```
export const AnchorAuthGuard = (rpc?: string): Type<CanActivate> => {
  class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    rpc = rpc || "https://eos.greymass.com";

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
      const [req] = context.getArgs();
      const { body } = req as { body: ProofPayload };

      const proof = IdentityProof.from(body.proof);

      const client = new APIClient({
        provider: new AxiosAPIProvider(this.rpc),
      });

      const accountName = proof.signer.actor;

      const account = await client.v1.chain.get_account(accountName);
      const auth = account.getPermission(proof.signer.permission).required_auth;
      const valid = proof.verify(auth, account.head_block_time);

      if (valid) {
        req.anchor = {
          account: {
            actor: proof.signer.actor.toString(),
            permission: proof.signer.permission.toString(),
          },
          object: account.toJSON(),
        };
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return AuthGuard;
};
```

However, now that I've packaged this up and extending the Guard with `extends` for some more functionality in a projhect I'm consuming the library in I'm having trouble figuring out how to enter the rpc parameter via `configService` from the ConfigModule and now feel like I'm not using the best practices here and that there's a better way from the start.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that by using a factory function for the class, you need to have different arguments based on the controller, and not a single one for the entire project, is this correct?

Comment: this question may be a better fit for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but to modify AuthGuard you must extend AuthGuard class and write over `canActivate` method.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector, private config: ConfigService) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    return super.canActivate(context); // this is necessary due to possibly returning `boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean>
  }
}
```